# Linux list all network namespaces

Tags: linux, networking, namespaces

I want to list all the network namespaces on my Linux machine. So far I found two recommended ways to do this:

```
ip netns list
```

And

```
lsns --type=net
```

Unfortunately both commands do not list all the namespaces! The first only lists the namespaces found in /var/run/netns and the second will only find namespaces with at least one process running in it. Docker for example will save its namespaces in /var/run/docker/netns (so they are not shown by ip netns) and there are some namespaces without a running process (so they are not shown by lsns). Is there any command that prints ALL the network namespaces on the host?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505112/how-do-i-find-all-interfaces-that-have-been-configured-in-linux-including-those

Comment: So there is no inbuilt tool for doing this? I have to scavenge the /proc file system to get all the namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once again came across this shortcoming of `lsns` and opened an [issue](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1881) in the repository. It is already fixed and in a future version of `lsns` it will show all the namespaces, even ones, that are only mounted with no process running in them. In the meantime the information is actually available in `/proc/mounts`. All mounts with the type `nsfs` should be mounted namespaces. This is not limited to network namespaces, but covers all namespaces.

Comment: One problem left: a namespace kept only by a file descriptor (not by a process being in this namespace): example `ip netns add foo; sleep 999 4< /run/netns/foo & sleep 2; ip netns delete foo` will keep the newly created namespace only with sleep's fd 4 (as can be then checked with `stat -f -L -c %T /proc/$(pidof sleep)/fd/4`). But `lsns` won't find it. And it appears it can't be mounted back (anymore?) unless opening it and setns-ing it.

Comment: You are correct. This seems like a pretty esoteric case to me though. Do you have more of a real-world example for this case?

Comment: No real use-case around. Just being pedantic about "*all* network namespaces". Anyway +1 for the move in the right direction with the request.

Comment: I also created an [issue](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1884) for this use case on the `lsns` repo. Apparently it is a legitimate use case for lxc and systemds nspawn.

Answer (score 2):

Not by name, but you can find all used namespaces by looking into /proc/{PID}/ns/net

This script (run as root) shows a list of used network namespace IDs on the machine:

```sh
find /proc/ -name ns 2>/dev/null |xargs -I NS ls -la NS/net 2> /dev/null| awk -F '->' '{print $2}'|sort -u
```

Comment: mounted-only namespaces won't be found

Comment: Yes, this trick works only with namespaces used by processes.

Answer (score 1):

To include the network namespaces of running docker containers into `ip netns list` you could just set a symbolic link (aka softlink) like this:

```
ln -Ts /var/run/docker/netns /var/run/netns
```

Unfortunately there is no generic command in linux to list all network namespaces. You could use the following python script to list at least all namespaces that are linked in `/var/run/netns`: https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Namespace/Namespace-Lister

For applications using other paths you would have to modify this script.

Comment: This will only solve the Problem for the specific Docker case. How would I know if any other application is creating namespaces in other locations?

Comment: Hi @Garuno, see my edit. There seems to be no general solution for this, but at least a script that you could tweak to serve your needs. Hope it helps!